# Why does image uploading fails with error as selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import os
import time
wait = WebDriverWait
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.arttoframe.com/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page_zazzleHeader_navSectionShop-title_7"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Start_over"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frame-canvas"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="computer"]').send_keys(os.getcwd()+"C://Users/Dell//Downloads//Living_Room.png")
```

---

```
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance i.e. the *driver* was unable to focus on the element identified through your *Locator Strategy*.

Your main issue is, you are trying to invoke `send_keys()` on an element with the *Locator Strategy* as:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="computer"]')
```

This *Locator Strategy* identifies a ***List*** element which is as follows:

```
<li id="computer" style="width:160px !important;" class="computer firstUpload" data-api="" data-value="upload" title="Computer"></li>
```

`<li>` tags doesn't accepts any *character sequence*. Only `<input>` tag accepts *character sequence*. So when you tried to invoke `send_keys()` *driver* was unable to set focus on the element.

Hence *image uploading* fails.

Element Snapshot:

[image: li_element]

Comment: So, Then how can I upload Image?

Comment: @PrashantSanap Perhaps to upload image you have to explore the other options e.g.  _AutoIT_ or _RIDE_ framework

Comment: @DebanjanB  Thanks